# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

When I call `renderFrame`, trying to access `newLine[i]` throws an error of

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Why is this? I've included the relevant code.

```
rows : ["-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-",],

generateLine : function(){
    var result = new Array(10);
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        result[i] = " ";
    }
},

renderFrame : function(){
    var newLine = this.generateLine();
    for(var i = 0; i < this.rows.length; i++){
        console.log(newLine[i]);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You forgot

```
return result;
```

at the end of `generateLine()`

So `newLine` is now undefined. Hence `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`